# Workload Scheduler bluemix

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, workload-scheduler

I have a PHP application that I have hosted in bluemix which just writes current time in a text file (sample application). Now I want to schedule it to run this application every 5 minutes on everyday using Workload Scheduler.

So I created this service and I included it and clicked "Launch Application Lab" on the Workload Scheduler from the dashboard.  I tried creating step for this link below.

> http://dmrt.au-syd.mybluemix.net/

but I couldn't able to run this page on schedule. Need help on how to do it in Application Lab

This is the step that I have followed:

1) Clicked on the Application Lab

2) Created a new process and have set valid from/to.

3) Created trigger (next tab) . I have taken the screenshot and attached it as link. Please refer from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_1YXYtMNYymZjFkX3JVQzNUcVE/view?usp=sharing).

4) Now in Steps tab I exactly don't know what to choose from the drop down for the bluemix link that I have shared so that I can run that page in schedule.

It would be a great help if anyone can tell me the procedure or steps that need to be followed.

Comment: I don't know how to schedule that link properly. I need steps.

Comment: For initial attempts please use a search engine or video sharing website or any other resource available online. Once you have attempted, and you can show us exactly what your problem is then we are prepared to help.

Comment: @ C_B I have already tried with "start a program, Webservice, RESTful " but I could able to get the output only once if I run it in RESTful by clicking run after enabling and in other cases I'm getting error. If I use webservice it is asking for operation which I dont know what to enter.

Comment: you shouldn't use ibm workLoad scheduler , you need to run it every 5 minutes, it would cost 0.05$ per job, that's mean 0.05$ every 5 minutes. it means 450 $ per month ... please be careful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to follow:

- Create a process library (Click "New" under "Process Library")
- Create a new process (select the process library you just created and
  click "New"
- Create a new step (Select the process, click "Step" and then click "New"). A pop-up appears
- Define a restful step.

  Select a step of type "Restful"

  Select your agent (you should have only one)

  Click the "Action" tab

  Fill the "Service URI" field with http://dmrt.au-syd.mybluemix.net

  Click OK

The panel should look like this: [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eleS3.png)

- Create the trigger

  Select trigger

  Click New

  In the "Repeat every" field set 5 minutes
- Select the process and click "Enable"

This should work!

Comment: you shouldn't use ibm workLoad scheduler , he need to run it every 5 minutes, it would cost 0.05$ per job, that's mean 0.05$ every 5 minutes. it means 450 $ per month ... please be careful

Comment: I, also, configured as you suggested (see https://developer.ibm.com/answers/storage/temp/13329-capture.png) but the job doesn't start each 5 min. Can you help me?